# unable to share my screen with my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

im trying to share my screen and record it but the problem its that when i choose the source of the stream, it doesnt start streaming, it only shows the window with the screen and window options to share but after selecting one, i checked that i get the ChromeMediaSource and the ChromeMediaSourceID but as i said, the dialog that says sharing wont appear and because of this i cant record anything.

This is an error i found debugging that is not logged into the console:

```
" at chrome-extension://mnoggiilghljimfhpghalhngdciecafi/background.js:16:31"
```

which is in "chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia" in the background file

this is my background file

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener( function( port ){
    // listen for messages from the port

    port.onMessage.addListener( function( message ){
        // send back a "pending" answer on the port
        port.postMessage( {
            "answer": 1,
            "state": "pending",
            "requestId": message.requestId
        } );
        chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen", "window"], port.sender.tab, function( id ){


            var response = {
                "answer": 1,
                "state": "completed",
                "requestId": message.requestId,
                "streamId": id || undefined
            };

            // send back a "completed" answer on the port
            port.postMessage( response );   
        } );
    } );
} );
```

this is the file that its loaded to the website using the extension

bridge.js

```
// open a port to communicate with background
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();

// create node
var node = document.createElement( 'div' );

// listen for messages from webpage and forward them to the background, through the previously opened port
window.addEventListener( 'message', function ( event ){
    if ( event.source != window || !event.data ){
        return;
    }
    // prevent to return answer to the background
    if( event.data.answer ){
        return;
    }

    port.postMessage( event.data );

} );

// listen for messages from background and forward them to the webpage
port.onMessage.addListener( function( data ){
    window.postMessage( data, '*' );
} );

// insert tag into parent page
node.id = 'extension-screensharing-installed';
document.body.appendChild( node );
```

manifest.js

```
{
  "name": "extension name",
  "description": "This extension allows you to share your screen",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "34",
  "icons": {
    "16": "img16.png",
    "48": "img48.png",
    "128": "img128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "bridge.js" ],
    "matches": [
      "https://*/tester"
      ]
  } ],
  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture",
    "https://*/tester"
  ]
}
```

could it be something wrong in my code?
i dont fully understand the error found by debuging

thanks!

edit: added manifest.json file!

Comment: Could you please also provide the other related files like `manifest.json`, which will help a lot for us to create the extension and start debugging?

Comment: oops! forgot about that!
the only relevant file missing was manifest.json

Comment: In fact I'm not that clear about what you want to get using above code, after user clicking the share button, what's next? I have no experience with the use of `chrome.desktopCapture`, but will [this](https://github.com/wpp/ScreenStream) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Developing a Chrome screen-sharing extension](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/screen-sharing/js/#chrome-extension) includes instructions and sample code on developing the extension wherein values for `apiKey`, `sessionId` and `token` were entered and `OT.registerScreenSharingExtension()` method was also used to register the screen-sharing extension.

```
    // API key and generate a test session ID and token:
    var apiKey    = "<YOUR_API_KEY>";
    var sessionId = "<YOUR_SESSION_ID>";
    var token     = "<YOUR_TOKEN>";

    var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

    session.connect(token, function(error) {
      var publisher = OT.initPublisher('camera');
      session.publish(publisher, function() {
        screenshare();
      });
    });

    session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
      session.subscribe(event.stream);
    });

    OT.registerScreenSharingExtension('chrome', '<YOUR_CHROME_EXTENSION_ID>', 2);
```

And for the recording part, you may check how they did it in [Screensharing with WebRTC](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/12/Screensharing-with-WebRTC?hl=en). Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer, after trying with this library i realized that it was also not working so after a HUGE code review i found out that i had a typo on the mediaConstraints object which is now working in both extensions!